# Base Class constructor parameter-values

Tags: c++, inheritance

So im new to c++ and i've been doing class inheritance lately,but im stuck over this problem.So problem is that when i create a derived class object,as far as i know the base class' constructor is called.Point is that my base class constructor needs one or more values to run and im not sure how i can supply them through my derived class.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
    public:
        Base( float a )
        {
            cout << a << "is a damn cool number!" << endl;
        }
};


class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        Derived( float b )
        {
            cout << b << "isnt cool at all" << endl;
        }
};


int main()
{
    Base a(5);
    Derived b(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, you need to decide where those values come from. Nobody on stackoverflow.com could possibly know that. Where does the base class's constructor's parameter comes from, when it is constructed as a base class of your derived class? Your C++ book should have plenty of examples of derived classes' constructors constructing base classes whose constructors take parameters. Which specific part of those examples you do not understand?

Comment: Welp problem is i don't have a book yet so im short on examples.

Comment: Alrighttt Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public:
    Derived( float b )
    : Base(b)
    {
        cout << b << "isnt cool at all" << endl;
    }
```

Worked